# How to unescape JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
'&quot;geocoded_waypoints&quot; : [
  {
     &quot;geocoder_status&quot; : &quot;OK&quot;,
     &quot;partial_match&quot; : true,
     &quot;place_id&quot; : &quot;ChIJ7_V-Dou62YgRXjw0MYaotfs&quot;,
     &quot;types&quot; : [ &quot;locality&quot;, &quot;political&quot; ]
  },
  {
     &quot;geocoder_status&quot; : &quot;OK&quot;,
     &quot;partial_match&quot; : true,
     &quot;place_id&quot; : &quot;ChIJRZdD6h5-1YcR_rYaYBXzk9E&quot;,
     &quot;types&quot; : [ &quot;locality&quot;, &quot;political&quot; ]
  }
```

And I want it to be parsed as regular JSON. How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: `s.replace(/&quot;/g,'"')`

Comment: is there some way to unescape it

Comment: Fix whatever code is generating the JSON to generate correct JSON with actual double quotation marks.

Comment: It seems to be HTML escaped. You should look for a tool for converting escaped HTML back to a normal string. Search for something like HTML unescape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```js
try {
  var mygoodJson = JSON.parse(badJson.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'););
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```